# Invalid Argument in pd.read_excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
f=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(r"F:\Mathnasium Project\Downloaded files")):
    for file in files:
        f.append(os.path.join("r"+'"'+root, file+'"'))


for x in f:
    print(x)
    z=pd.read_excel(x)
    student_report=pd.merge(student_report,z,how='left',left_on='Student Name',right_on='Student')
```

an error comes up as invalid argument in the pd.read_excel()

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'r"F:\\Mathnasium Project\\Downloaded files\\Abdelrahman Mahmoud LP  05_11_2020.xlsx"'
```

and i don't know why, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong here:
f.append(os.path.join("r"+'"'+root, file+'"'))

Try to print all values of 'f' and check whether it is a valid string or not to be passed to read_excel.
like
new_file=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\a\b\c\Raw Data\CO\acb.xls")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to build a raw string to deal with backslashes in `os.path.join("r"+'"'+root, file+'"')`, but it doesn't work that way. The "r" is used when writing string literals like `r"F:\Mathnasium Project\Downloaded files"` in source files so that python's conversion of the text into a python string is not tripped up by the backslashes.

Once its a python string, there is no raw/not-raw variant. Any escaping is complete.  All you really did was create a string

```
'r"F:\\Mathnasium Project\\Downloaded files\\Abdelrahman Mahmoud LP  05_11_2020.xlsx"'
```

and a windows path can't literally start with the characters `'r', '"', 'F', ':'`. Instead, just join the already properly contructed strings from walk.

```
f=[]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(r"F:\Mathnasium Project\Downloaded files")):
    for file in files:
        f.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys this really helped me :) it solved it :)